# Gnu make: read recipe output into make variable

Tags: shell, gnu-make

Is it possible to take a part of the output of a recipe line and use to to set a make variable? For example:

```
%.o: %.cc
    $(eval __time_$* := $(shell date "+%s.%N"))
    $(COMPILE.cc) -o $@ $<
    @echo `date +%s.%N` - $(__time_$*) | bc | xargs printf "%s compile time %6.3f sec\n" $@
```

Instead of `echo`'ing the time I want to capture it in a make variable. However, when I use `eval` and `shell` instead of the 3rd line above, similar to the 1st line, make appears to read all lines at once, and then schedule the actual recipe shell calls for later. So the result is that the recipe lines are all evaluated at once, so there is little time difference.

Comment: @MadScientist, care to take a crack at this?

Comment: Why not just use  "time $(COMPILE.cc) -o $@ $<"

Comment: @wojtow, the point is to get the time info back into the make file. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Make will always expand the entire recipe, including all lines, before it starts any shell commands.  So you can't do this using eval etc.  In fact I don't think there's any way to do it with make variables only; at least I can't think of one.  You don't say WHY you want to put the elapsed time in a make variable.  You can redefine the `SHELL` make variable to use something that records the time taken for that shell instance, but I don't know of any way to get that information back into a make variable, easily.

Comment: @MadScientist, I wanted to get the time to run each compilation recipe and generate some stats, like min, max and average, and then send them to stdout via `info` function. It appears that this type of thing would need to be done outside of make.

Comment: Well, make is not very good at math so generating stats using make, even if you had the raw data, will not be simple.  I suspect using your own SHELL implementation that records the time spent for each invocation, possibly using an environment variable to record the name of the target for example, then a separate operation at the end that uses some other tool to do the computation will work out better for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to do what you want is to run the compiler inside a $(shell).  One problem with doing this is that Make doesn't seem to see the errors, when the command in $(shell) fails.  Other than that, here's what I think you wanted:

```
%.o: %.cc
    $(eval __start_$* := $(shell date "+%s.%N"))
    @echo $(shell $(COMPILE.cc) -o $@ $<)
    $(eval __dur_$* := $(shell echo `date +%s.%N` - $(__time_$*) | bc | xargs printf "%s compile time %6.3f sec\n" $@))
```

Due to the caveat mentioned above, I recommend using the 'time' command to collect these stats, as @wojtow said.  If you have different requirements, consider wrapping compilation with a script that collects your timing data and logs it to a file.  Then, process the contents of the file as a post-processing step.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I can see to do what you want is to run the compiler
>   inside a $(shell). One problem with doing this is that Make doesn't
>   seem to see the errors, when the command in $(shell) fails.

Droid Coder presented a clever approach. A way to solve the problem of `make` not seeing errors (thereby not aborting on error) is to pass the exit status via the output of the command, while the original compiler output (if any) is redirected to the standard error stream. The rule then is e. g.:

```
%.o: %.cc
    $(eval __start_$* := $(shell date "+%s.%N"))
    exit $(shell $(COMPILE.cc) -o $@ $< >&2; echo $$?)
    $(eval __dur_$* := $(shell echo `date +%s.%N` - $(__time_$*) | bc …))
```